# setUndecorated(true) messing with toFront()

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have these two JFrames that work just fine when setUndecorated is set to false, but it doesn't work consistently when it's set to true;

```
frame = new JFrame("Name of the frame"); // main frame
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
frame.setSize(width, height);
frame.add(canvas);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);

menu = new MenuUI(); // this is also a undecorated JFrame
```

menu is called by a mouse event, but it sometimes shows up in the front and sometimes it shows in the back of the main frame...

```
public static void checkMove(int action, MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    if(x == 0){
        menu.setVisible(true);
        menu.toFront();
    }else{
        menu.setVisible(false);
    }
```

I've tried to do `frame.toBack();` but it sends the frame behind everything else as well...
How can I bring undecorated JFrame in front of another undecorated JFrame and make it consistent?

EDIT: the menu frame disappears on mouse event

```
contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

EDIT2: after mKorbel's answer, I've tried to create a JDialog, but I get the same result as with JFrame. How can I set the parent if I extend a JDialog?

```
package menu;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

import openGL.main.openGLMain;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class menuTest extends JDialog {

public menuTest() {
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBounds(0, 0, 250, frame.getHeight());
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 450, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 700, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) by default never react to AlwaysOnTop or toFront correctly, isn't main functionality for primary [Top-Level Containe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)r (without iconify and deiconify, but then flashing on the screen)
- you have to use [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for this job, [set for parent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog-java.awt.Dialog-boolean-) and [modality (if needed)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)

Comment: I've edited the question based on your answer, but I'm still having some trouble setting up the parent frame

Comment: okay, so I figured it out... Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

JFrame by default never react to AlwaysOnTop or toFront correctly, isn't main functionality for primary Top-Level Container (without iconify and deiconify, but then flashing on the screen)

you have to use JDialog for this job, set for parent and modality (if needed)

---

exactly and also you can use JinternalFrame that makes you have some children frame in your main Jframe and you can iconify and deiconify or close which is don't needed and also make them resizable if you need.
and if you want make them in front or back to others,you can make it easily by Drag&Drop that Frame Children!